# How do we go about factorizing boolean expressions?

Tags: boolean-algebra

How do we know how to go about factorizing a boolean expression when there are so many ways?

For example, the factorized form of $ABC + A'B'C'$ is $(A + C')(B' + C)(A' + B)$, but how do we know how to derive this result?

Comment: This is not *the* factorized form, but *a* factorized form; it follows by symmetry that $(A'+C)(B+C')(A+B')$ is another.

Answer (score 1):

$ABC+A'B\,'C'$ is a *sum of products* form or, if you’re thinking of it in logical terms, a *disjunctive normal form*; $(A + C')(B' + C)(A' + B)$ is a *product of sums* form or, in logical terms, a *conjunctive normal form*. There are algorithms for converting Boolean expressions to product of sums form and logical expressions to conjunctive normal form; you might start with the Wikipedia articles on [canonical forms in Boolean algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form_%28Boolean_algebra%29) and [conjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form).