# how do you factor this boolean equation?

Tags: boolean-algebra

How do you factor this boolean equation $A'B'CD+AB'CD'+AB'C'D+ABCD$
I need help with where do I start from.
What are the factors?

Comment: There are many examples on how to factor boolean expressions, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384304/how-do-we-go-about-factorizing-boolean-expressions) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384304/how-do-we-go-about-factorizing-boolean-expressions). Please research your question and if you still can not figure it out explain where you are getting stuck.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Draw the **complement** of the Karnaugh map corresponding to the given equation. Obtain a minimal sum of products, then apply DeMorgan's Law to this complement expression to obtain a minimal product of sums.